# How to get console text to refresh rather than re-type?

Tags: c++, console, smoothing

Hi so i'm making a game through the console window, and i was wondering if there was any way to just get maybe one or two text character's placement to change or disappear. Usually to accomplish this i would have to tell the console to re-type every single character and line all over again, but this just takes to long (1 second fps plus .5 second time spent re-typing the scene).

**Is there some way i could re-fresh or change one or two lines or 'characters' seen on the console so so much time is not spent on waiting for the console to re-typing my 24 lines, each a string? (the scene made up of text)**

**Thanks!** =)

btw... does anyone remember that little easter egg in windows which was an entire star wars movie made out of text in the console?? I want the game be smooth like that!

Comment: `telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use an external library to interface with the console as C++ doesn't have these capabilities, but it is possible.

My old goto for this sort of thing is [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). It's straightforward, quick to set up, and cross-platform. But it's **old**, and its age shows. (If you're on windows you'll have to use [pdcurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/); same capabilities, different package).

There are also console-specific ways of doing this. In particular, Windows provides an API for performing these sorts of actions.

Answer (score 3):

You need ncurses library.
See [console print w/o scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408965/console-print-w-o-scrolling) for reasons and examples.

Also google for the source to the rogue/urogue/nethack games which do that already.

Comment: Yup, I used to implement my OS homework "producer-consumer" in console with this.