# Colorizing Windows command line output from PHP

Tags: php, colors, cmd

To output colored text in bash, you use [ANSI escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php).

How do you output colored text on a Windows command line, specifically from PHP?

Comment: Good question! Although I think `cmd.exe` is plain incapable of this.

Comment: Ah, it seems to be possible after all.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77744/how-can-i-change-the-text-color-in-the-windows-command-prompt

Comment: @Pekka I saw this one too, but seems too much work for what it's worth. Though for curiosity: http://www.mailsend-online.com/blog/setting-windows-console-text-colors-in-c.html

Comment: I've wondered the same for years. Plain ANSI escape codes used to work fine in Windows 95/98 but they never got to NT/2000.

Comment: I old old times of DOS 6.22 you'd need to load ANSI.SYS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI.SYS to enable ASNI escape codes in DOS prompt.

Answer (score 10):

Download dynwrap.dll from : http://www.script-coding.com/dynwrap95.zip

Then extract it to `%systemroot%\system32` directory and then run following command in command line:

`regsvr32.exe "%systemroot%\system32\dynwrap.dll"`

You'll get a success message which means dynwrap.dll is registered.

Then you can use it this way :

```
$com = new COM('DynamicWrapper');

// register needed features
$com->Register('kernel32.dll', 'GetStdHandle', 'i=h', 'f=s', 'r=l');
$com->Register('kernel32.dll', 'SetConsoleTextAttribute', 'i=hl', 'f=s', 'r=t');

// get console handle
$ch = $com->GetStdHandle(-11);
```

some example:

```
$com->SetConsoleTextAttribute($ch, 4);
echo 'This is a red text!';
$com->SetConsoleTextAttribute($ch, 7);
echo 'Back to normal color!';
```

colors codes:
7 => default
0 => black
1 => blue
2 => green
3 => aqua
4 => red
5 => purple
6 => yellow
7 => light gray
8 => gray
9 => light blue
10 => light green
11 => light aqua
12 => light red
13 => light purple
14 => light yellow
15 => white

Comment: `regsvr32.exe "%systemroot%\system32\dynwrap.dll"` don't work for me on Windows 7, 64bit. This work for me instead http://softkube.com/blog/ansi-command-line-colors-under-windows/

Comment: @Sawny you should post this as a complete answer, it worked for me on Windows 8 x64!!!

Comment: @Sawny - you are a life saver! I have been looking for this answer for years. Not only will your answer do colors - BUT - it will also do the rest of the ANSI stuff - like move the cursor to a new location! I just want to weep. You have no idea just how long I have been looking for this! It is a God send. Thanks a million times!

Answer (score 7):

ANSI escape sequences are now supported in Windows since Windows 10 1511.
You can run the below code from `cmd` with `php`, and you will get the results in color if you are running Windows 10 1511 and above.

```
<?php
echo "\033[31mRed\n".    // Red Color Text 
     "\033[32mGreen\n".  // Green Color Text
     "\033[33mYellow\n". // Yellow Color Text
     "\033[34mBlue\n".   // Blue Color Text
     "\033[37mWhite\n";  // White Color Text
?>
```

I am running Windows 10 1903, and below screenshot shows my output of the script in cmd:

[image]

For the complete escape sequence reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences

Answer (score 6):

Windows 10 supports color in terminal natively ([full reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences)).

Prior to Windows 10, ANSI escape codes were not available in Windows Command Prompt, natively. For older Windows you can try:

- patching cmd.exe with ansihack.exe http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=130&lang=en :)
- http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon/index.html

On bash shell it works like a charm and there is even a php lib for that: http://sourceforge.net/projects/milcovlib/

If it's an overkill for you you can try this:

```
echo "\033[31mred\033[37m\r\n";
echo "\033[32mgreen\033[37m\r\n";
echo "\033[41;30mblack on red\033[40;37m\r\n";
```

Here is the list of bash color codes:

```
$black = "33[0;30m";
$darkgray = "33[1;30m";
$blue = "33[0;34m";
$lightblue = "33[1;34m";
$green = "33[0;32m";
$lightgreen = "33[1;32m";
$cyan = "33[0;36m";
$lightcyan = "33[1;36m";
$red = "33[0;31m";
$lightred = "33[1;31m";
$purple = "33[0;35m";
$lightpurple = "33[1;35m";
$brown = "33[0;33m";
$yellow = "33[1;33m";
$lightgray = "33[0;37m";
$white = "33[1;37m";
```

Comment: The output for me (`cmd.exe` on Win 7) was `←[31mred←[37m`

Comment: yes, AFAIK cmd.exe can't display ANSI, and php does not love Win32 Console API.

Comment: Yea, all of the material I've found was directed to bash using the escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that using plain escape codes won't work on the Windows command prompt. The answers on [the other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77744/how-can-i-change-the-text-color-in-the-windows-command-prompt) related to this say that you need to use the Win32 API. A Win32 API library does exist for PHP, however [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.w32api.php) does have a large red section warning that it is **experimental**. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with php-wcli extension. This extension use native Windows functionality instead of third party ansi emulator. https://github.com/ZmotriN/php-wcli

Comment: This qualifies as "link-only answer" - could you post code snippet/piece of text from linked page describing the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo chr(27); //Escape char.
echo "5;31;47"; //Graphic mode blink red on white
```

Don't have a shell/php env under my hand but this should output precisely what you want.

Comment: This is the output I got with that: `←5;31;47`

Comment: @Andreas This seems to be the output returned on Windows systems. The provided solution only works on Linux and can't be achieved on the Windows CLI because there are only two colors (16 are available but you can only have two at the same time).

Comment: Yes, I specifically specified in my question that I'm looking for a Windows solution.

Comment: Sorry, the "bash" part of your question made me overlook the "windows" part. As I told Pekka, this isn't feasible by standards means. You would need to write a whole new program to output colors and then, you'd have to pipe the php output in it,...

Comment: As stated before: https://softkube.com/blog/ansi-command-line-colors-under-windows works.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 (compilation 19042.1110) PHP 7.4, this worked for me:

```
echo("\x1b[31m Memory Testing \x1b[0m \n\r");
```

The escape sequence is "\x1b["

"\x1b[31m" is for red color

"\x1b[0m" is for 'normal' color

The color codes are [here](https://www.shellhacks.com/bash-colors/)

I hope to be helpful.