# Do windows console color values have official names (constants) associated with them?

Tags: c++, windows, colors, console

Normally colors are called through their hexadecimal associations, but in the code is it possible to call these colors trough some constants build in windows console API ?

Here are colors names I found while searching SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138277/393087

colors codes:

```
7 => default
0 => black
1 => blue
2 => green
3 => aqua
4 => red
5 => purple
6 => yellow
7 => light gray
8 => gray
9 => light blue
A => light green
B => light aqua
C => light red
D => light purple
E => light yellow
F => white
```

Are these names official ? So for example I could do:

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,LIGHT_BLUE * 16 + LIGHT_AQUA);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Console Screen Buffers - Character Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes)

```
FOREGROUND_BLUE         Text color contains blue.
FOREGROUND_GREEN        Text color contains green.
FOREGROUND_RED          Text color contains red.
FOREGROUND_INTENSITY    Text color is intensified.
BACKGROUND_BLUE         Background color contains blue.
BACKGROUND_GREEN        Background color contains green.
BACKGROUND_RED          Background color contains red.
BACKGROUND_INTENSITY    Background color is intensified.
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is complete list of **Background** and **Foreground** colors in WinAPI.

```
/*Enum to store Foreground colors*/
    typedef enum FG_COLORS 
    {
        FG_BLACK = 0,
        FG_BLUE = 1,
        FG_GREEN = 2,
        FG_CYAN = 3,
        FG_RED = 4,
        FG_MAGENTA = 5,
        FG_BROWN = 6,
        FG_LIGHTGRAY = 7,
        FG_GRAY = 8,
        FG_LIGHTBLUE = 9,
        FG_LIGHTGREEN = 10,
        FG_LIGHTCYAN = 11,
        FG_LIGHTRED = 12,
        FG_LIGHTMAGENTA = 13,
        FG_YELLOW = 14,
        FG_WHITE = 15
    }FG_COLORS;

    /*Enum to store Background colors*/
    typedef enum BG_COLORS 
    {
        BG_NAVYBLUE = 16,
        BG_GREEN = 32,
        BG_TEAL = 48,
        BG_MAROON = 64,
        BG_PURPLE = 80,
        BG_OLIVE = 96,
        BG_SILVER = 112,
        BG_GRAY = 128,
        BG_BLUE = 144,
        BG_LIME = 160,
        BG_CYAN = 176,
        BG_RED = 192,
        BG_MAGENTA = 208,
        BG_YELLOW = 224,
        BG_WHITE = 240
    }BG_COLORS;
```