# C++ Win32 Console Color

Tags: c++, winapi, colors, console

I know a bit how to do colors in Win32 C++ console. But it's not really efficient. For example:

```
 SYSTEM("color 01")
```

Slows down a lot on your process. Also:

```
 HANDLE h = GetStdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
 WORD wOldColorAttrs;
 CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbiInfo;

 /*
  * First save the current color information
  */

 GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(h, &csbiInfo);
 wOldColorAttrs = csbiInfo.wAttributes;

 /*
  * Set the new color information
  */

 SetConsoleTextAttribute ( h, FOREGROUND_RED );
```

Works great, but it doesn't have much colors. Also, `FOREGROUND_RED` is dark-red.

So what I want to ask, isn't there a way like CLR property `Console::ForegroundColor` set, so you can use any color from the ConsoleColor enum?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `FOREGROUND_INTENSITY` flag to make it bright-red? For example: `SetConsoleTextAttribute( h, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY )`

Comment: That works, but still I wonder if there's any way to get more colors, maybe with palette?

Comment: Console only supports 16 colors, which are created by combining FOREGROUND_RED, FOREGROUND_BLUE, FOREGROUND_GREEN and FOREGROUND_INTENSITY.

Comment: There are 16 colors.  Actual color values are retrieved from a color table.  Editable by the user in the system menu.  And you can update it in code, SetConsoleScreenBufferEx() function.

Comment: More colors are coming: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/09/22/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The console only supports 16 colors, which are created by combining the four values as follows (I might have got the gray/darkgray confused, but you get the idea):

```
namespace ConsoleForeground
{
  enum {
    BLACK             = 0,
    DARKBLUE          = FOREGROUND_BLUE,
    DARKGREEN         = FOREGROUND_GREEN,
    DARKCYAN          = FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
    DARKRED           = FOREGROUND_RED,
    DARKMAGENTA       = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
    DARKYELLOW        = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN,
    DARKGRAY          = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
    GRAY              = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY,
    BLUE              = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
    GREEN             = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_GREEN,
    CYAN              = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
    RED               = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_RED,
    MAGENTA           = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
    YELLOW            = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN,
    WHITE             = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
  };
}
```

Comment: You can just remove all of the assignments and it will still work because the color codes are in increasing order.

Comment: It is worth noting that by using [`SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolescreenbufferinfoex) one can change the colours. They are not set into stone, changing the palette is perfectly possible.

Answer (score 2):

The console only has a limited set of colors. The .NET implementation uses [`ConsoleColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor.aspx) to set colors which is just an enumeration of 16 colors.

The underlying Win32 console has 8 base colors that's doubled through the use of the intensity flag (as mentioned in Shaktal's comment under your question).

Answer (score 1):

Here is full list of **Background** and **ForeGround** colors.
[Complete list of WinAPI colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49929936/6219626)