# Changing Color of Text In C++ Console

Tags: c++

I’m trying to change the color of my text in c++ i have scavengend the internet at this point. Could anyone help me I tried using “#include ” but that still does not work.

I swear i always forget to include this but i’m on Windows

Comment: Unfortunately there's no completely cross platform solution in standard  C++. We'd need to know what platform you're on.

Comment: my bad forgot to include i’m on Windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Win32 Console Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125440/c-win32-console-color)

Comment: Most of the possible answers won't work unless you enable support, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/16755142/103167

Answer (score 0):

I can't offer you a proper C++'ish solution, but - C libraries work well with C++, and [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html) can be your friend. Quoting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10487615/1593077):

```
#include <curses.h>

int main() {
    initscr();
    start_color();
    init_pair(1, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_RED);
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    printw("This should be printed in black with a red background!\n");
    refresh();
    getch(); // so the program doesn't just quit immediately
    endwin(); // not very RAII, is it? :-(
}
```

Remember to link with `-lcurses` (on Unix-like machines); or use `find_package(Curses REQUIRED)` in your `CMakeLists.txt`, if you use CMake.