# Windows Console (conhost) discards newline when output matches witdth of the window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console

I have a C++ application on Windows, that logs to stdout (via the Win32 api using WriteConsole). Each logline consists of some text and a trailing newline character. The problem is:

**When the width of the log-text (not including the newline character) matches the width of the console window, the newline character gets discarded.**

See this example:

[image]

There are 3 log-messages:

- the first one is smaller than the console-width
- the second one matches the console-width exactly
- the third one is longer than the console width, and thus wraps.

If I resize the window, the following happens:

[image]

The second and third line got merged into a single line, despite a newline character being printed between them. I suspect that windows, in an attempt to be smart, discarded the newline after the second message, since it would have visually led to a gap between the second and third message (new line from word wrapping + my newline charater). This is all well and good for that console-width, but when I resize, everything breaks.

Strive Sun - MSFT pointed out in their answer, that this behavior seems to happen due to the ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING  flag being set. Disabling it fixes the issue. I use this flag to enable outputs of different colors, so would like to find some way to fix the newlines without losing colored output.

**Is there some way to tell Windows not to do that (without disabling ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING to not lose colors)?**

Comment: cmd has nothing to do with this. It's a shell which has to be attached to some console (like conhost.exe or Windows terminal). It's the console that prints the texts out

Comment: Ok, I guess conhost.exe is the issue then. I am still going to leave the title the way it is, since I would not have searched for conhost. So if there are other people in my situation I doubt they would find this post.

Comment: @pulp_user Add both console and conhost, remove cmd.exe since it’s irrelevant. And actually try starting the application without using cmd.exe - the latter may be changing console state and making it behave “weirdly”.

Comment: I am not starting my application using cmd.exe, I just double click. I guess cmd.exe is not at involved then, its just my application and conhost (I thought cmd and conhost were the same thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there some way to tell Windows not to do that?**

After some debugging, I found that this problem will not occur after removing the [ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolemode#parameters)  style in the console.

Like this,

```
DWORD lp;
HANDLE std_out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
GetConsoleMode(std_out, &lp);
SetConsoleMode(std_out, lp &~ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING );
...
```

Updated:

```
int main()
{
    DWORD lp;
    HANDLE std_out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleMode(std_out, &lp);
    SetConsoleMode(std_out, lp & ~ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING);

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(std_out, FOREGROUND_RED);
    DWORD written;
    char str1[] = "aaaaaa\n";
    char str2[] = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\r\ndddddd";
    //    char str2[] = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n";
    char str3[] = "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc\n";
    int len = strlen(str2);
    WriteConsoleA(std_out, str1, strlen(str1), &written, NULL);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(std_out, FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    WriteConsoleA(std_out, str2, strlen(str2), &written, NULL);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(std_out, FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_GREEN); 
    WriteConsoleA(std_out, str3, strlen(str3), &written, NULL);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

More colors, please refer: [C++ Win32 Console Color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17125539/11128312)

Comment: This does indeed work, however I have ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING active to enable colored text output and would like to keep that. I edited the question to make that clear. Seems for now like those two things are mutually exclusive. (I tried out other flags that might interfere with newlines, but I didn't find a combination that fixes the newlines and lets me keep colored output).

Comment: @pulp_user In fact, you canceled accepting my answer, I was a little frustrated. Because it explains your original problem. For your new question, I suggest you can use [SetConsoleTextAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute) instead.

Comment: Thank you! I'll test that as soon as I have the possibility. I didn't mean to upset anybody, but just realized that its kind of counterproductive to leave an answer as accepted, if there is still a (newly added) part of the question that I'd like to have an answer to. So no ill will.

Comment: It does. Its still not 100% what I wanted, since I have way fewer colours now, but I guess the ideal solution I want just doesn't exist, and at this point I'd be a monster not to let you leave this question behind you in peace :D. Thanks for investing so much time into it!

Comment: @pulp_user There seems to be no better way to get more colors. Maybe someone knows a better answer. You can post a new question to ask about this.

Answer (score 0):

I found that, if one wants to keep using ANSI escape codes and not getting strange errors with linebreaks, passing this to ConsoleMode should suffice:

```cpp
auto h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleMode(h, ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING);
```

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work for me unfortunately.