# PHP: color a string

Tags: php

I've just finished an ASCII table design like:

```
+------+------+
|id    |name  |
+------+------+
|1     |x     |
+------+------+
```

now I'm trying to color those text. I found some way with PHP image/HTML way. Is there any way to color those text without PHP image create/HTML.

**Objective:** Color each column's text with same color. eg. all values of `id` col with color 'red', `name` col with green and so on.

***NOTE:*** It's not a console output nor a HTML page. Just draw with PHP, inspired from [here](https://gist.github.com/doubleking/6117215)

Please help me.

Comment: Can you be more specific please on what you are doing?

Comment: Is this for console output?

Comment: Please be more accurate in your question about what you are trying to accomplish. If this is a table you are going to show on a website, you need to use html/css to style the elements.

Comment: just try <td style="color:#000;">id</td>

Comment: not console output nor HTML page, just inspired by https://gist.github.com/doubleking/6117215. so looking if possible to color those texts

Comment: It doesn't answer the question : "where do you want to print it ?"

Answer (score 0):

This really depends where you are going to output the table.

If you are using a command shell (dos-window, bash etc.) then you can use some special escape codes or [api functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086034/colorizing-windows-command-line-output-from-php) to color your output.
If you are using a browser which gets mime type text/text you can't color anything.
If you are using a browser which gets mime type text/html you can use CSS with fixed char sizes (font courier)

In fact you need to tell us, where do you wan't to output your table.