# java System.err.println output is red

Tags: java, fonts, output

I am programming following thing:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
System.err.println("Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol");
}
```

My output is:

> Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol

Which seems ok but the font color of the output is red. It should be black.
How do I make the output black?

Comment: In what environment?

Comment: This is not problem of your Java code, this is your console setting.

Comment: why did you print out `err` instead of `out`? `err` is standard printed red because it's used for errors like `err` should suggest

Comment: Intellij Community edition

Comment: how do I change these settings

Comment: `System.err.println` prints red because it is an error while `System.out.println` prints black...

Comment: I didn't know that System.out.println existed. I thought that err existed for Ending Readable Reddit message, not for error.

Comment: so the easiest is to change `err` to `out` [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/system-in-out-error.html) you find some informations about that and I suggest to read a bit more on this topic because if you change the color in your IDE and you have a lot ouf output in your console, it could be hard to find a printed out error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must use

```
System.out.println("Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol");
```

err is always red in default if you want change it you must change your ide setting

Answer (score 5):

This is due to your console, not Java code. The console is displaying stderr differently from stdout, to make it stand out a bit more.

In IntelliJ IDEA (which you mentioned in your comments), the setting is:

> Preferences -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Console error output

Change that to whatever color you want.

Answer (score 1):

that is because you are printing an error you should use `System.out.println()`

Answer (score 1):

The color of standard error is environment specific and nothing to do with your code. That said for various environment there are various ways :

For IntelliJ go to Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> ConsoleColors

Change the colors as per your wish.

for unix console refer to
[How to set font color for stdout and stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841143/how-to-set-font-color-for-stdout-and-stderr)

for windows cmd console refer to
[How can i change the text color in the windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77744/how-can-i-change-the-text-color-in-the-windows-command-prompt)